# Unable to use Td tag in Php if statement

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to create a table with data values shown through php,
but am unable to use td tag in PHP if statement.

For instance:

```
 <tr>
<td>Octroi: Rs. </td>
<td> <?php 
echo (round($r));
?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>+ VAT: Rs. </td>
<td> <?php 
echo ($l);
?>  </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
<?php 
$a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
if($a > 100000)
            {   
               <td>+ TCS: Rs. </td>
               <td>
                $tcs=(round(.01*$a));
                echo '<p>' . "+ TCS: Rs. $tcs" . '</p>';
                </td>
            }   
 ?>
```

But when using without td tag in 3rd row - it works:

```
 <tr>
<td>Octroi: Rs. </td>
<td> <?php 
echo (round($r));
?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>+ VAT: Rs. </td>
<td> <?php 
echo ($l);
?>  </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
<?php 
$a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
if($a > 100000)
            {   
                $tcs=(round(.01*$a));
                echo '<p>' . "+ TCS: Rs. $tcs" . '</p>';
            }   
 ?>
```

How can I correct the first Code given for TCS calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is **HTML tags** inside **PHP**. Before closing PHP tag anything you write is considered as a PHP script. So HTML tags are ignore inside PHP script. (IF you write it without `echo`)

You need to close PHP tag first then write your HTML tags and then reopen the PHP tag. After closing PHP tag you still have access to all PHP variables assigned in above script.

So Update your code as follow:

```
<?php 
$a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
if($a > 100000)
            { 
               ?>  
               <td>+ TCS: Rs. </td>
               <td>

                <?php 
                    $tcs=(round(.01*$a));
                    echo '<p>' . "+ TCS: Rs. $tcs" . '</p>'; 
                ?>

                </td>
<?php
            } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Alok, it works just last one more thing - in line - echo '<p>' . "+ TCS: Rs. $tcs" . '</p>'; if we dont want to use '<p>' '</p>' tag then should we use ().

Comment: You can simply print it in double quotes. As it's just simple PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to echo those td tags. when you want PHP to output HTML code you need to echo it.

```
$a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
if($a > 100000)
     {   
         echo '<td>+ TCS: Rs. </td>
               <td>';
                $tcs=(round(.01*$a));
                echo '<p>' . "+ TCS: Rs. $tcs" . '</p>';
                echo '</td>';
         }   
>
```

Comment: Thanks Eduard, it works just last one more thing - in line - echo '<p>' . "+ TCS: Rs. $tcs" . '</p>'; if we dont want to use '<p>' '</p>' tag then should we use ().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Octroi: Rs. </td>
    <td> <?php echo (round($r)); ?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>+ VAT: Rs. </td>
    <td> <?php echo ($l); ?>  </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
    <?php 
        $a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
        if($a > 100000)
            {   
               echo "<td>+ TCS: Rs. </td><td>
               " . $tcs=(round(.01*$a)); . " <p>+ TCS: Rs. " . $tcs . " </p>
                </td>";
            }   
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about basic PHP syntax here, you should wrap your html tags with quotes

```
"<td>"
```

or close the php tag write you html and open it again, like

```
?> <td>some text</td> <?php
```

Last option would be to use `php heredoc` for that.